# In CSS Generated Content Module Level 3, is the generated content defined to be displayed on the document tree?

Tags: css, pseudo-element, w3c

[Chapter 5 of Cascading Style Sheets Level 2 Revision 2](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/selector.html#pseudo-elements) states that the generated content (pseudo-elements) does not appear in the document source or document tree.

> Neither pseudo-elements nor pseudo-classes appear in the document source or document tree.

---

However, the above description did not exist in CSS Pseudo-Elements Module Level 4, CSS Generated Content Module Level 3, and Selectors Level 3.

Also, according to [CSS Generated Content Module Level 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-content-3/#accessibility), the generated content should be searchable, selectable, and assistive technology should be able to use the content information.

> Generated content should be searchable, selectable, and available to assistive technologies. The content property applies to speech and generated content must be rendered for speech output.

From the above, I believe that there is no guarantee in the CSS Generated Content Module Level 3 that the generated content containing the pseudo-elements will not be on the document tree . In CSS Generated Content Module Level 3, is the generated content defined to be displayed on the document tree?

Answer (score 0):

I would not count on the generated content being selectable, searchable, or available to assistive tech anytime soon, but be prepared for it anyway. It should be, but it is not. At some point browsers will probably implement this aspect of the spec, but I would not hold your breath as to when... When/if the browsers do implement this aspect of the spec, I do not think that will involve making generated content part of the dom. IF they did, that would not be backwards compatible, and thus should require a different doc type.

For generated content to be selectable, searchable, and available to assistive tech, it need not be a part of the dom. I would think that it would actually be easier for browsers to implement the availability of generated content to such ui tools, by changing how the ui accesses the rendered doc, as opposed to changing how the doc gets rendered. Meaning, my guess is that if/when generated content becomes available to various ui tools (search/select/screen-readers) it will still not be a part of the dom.

The reason being that, the dom is structured and populated before styles are applied. I'm not an expert on how the browsers render content, but I understand enough to know that having the css actually inject content into the dom would require a major change in the rendering process. Additionally, it does not really make sense that css should be fundamentally altering the structure of the dom, for it to do so, would be kind of going against the basis of what css is meant to be.

On the other hand, changing how the ui tools access rendered content need not involve fundamentally altering the rendering process. The rendered page, including the generated content, exists in the browser. Currently ui tools, like search/select/screen-readers, operate on the dom, but there is no fundamental reason why they must. These ui tools could just as easily operate on the finally rendered result.

My guess is that these ui tools operating on the dom is kind of a legacy implementation which has yet to be redesigned but really should be redesigned. The ui tools should be operating on the final output. Now with things like shadow dom coming about the need for the ui tools to operate on final rendered content rather than dom becomes even more obvious.

So I do not think generated content will become part of the dom in the future, though it should, and may, become selectable, searchable and available to assistive tech.